# SKSTableView Got wrong Indexpath when clicked Button inside SubRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, cocoapods

I am using `SKSTableView` control.I have added button on cell.I have facing one issue When i clicked on button then i got wrong row and subrow.

```
 - (IBAction)btnPickListPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=sender;
    PicklistTableViewCell *cell = (PicklistTableViewCell *)btn.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblView indexPathForCell:cell];
   NSLog("%@",indexPath.row);
   NSLog("%@"indexPath.subRow);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First copy below code and open SKSTableView.h

```
- (NSIndexPath *)correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

paste this below to `@interface SKSTableView : UITableView` in SKSTableView.h

and replace your action method code to this:

```
UIButton *btn=sender;
PicklistTableViewCell *cell = (PicklistTableViewCell *)btn.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSIndexPath *correspondingIndexPath = [self.tblView correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog("%@",correspondingIndexPath.row);
NSLog("%@"correspondingIndexPath.subRow);
```